# GPars is part of Groovy but not in the API docs? Why can't I import?

Tags: groovy, gpars

http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/gettingStarted.html#gettingStarted_downloadingAndInstalling

It says that GPars has been incorporated into Groovy. If so, why can't I find it in the API documentation for Groovy? Why is it that my import statements don't seem to be working? I see the library in my Groovy distro:

```
user@box /opt/stuff/groovy $ find . -name "*gpars*"
./lib/gpars-1.2.1.jar
user@box /opt/stuff/groovy $
```

Comment: What version of Groovy? It's still a separate library, just because it's bundled doesn't mean its documentation is in the main Groovy docs. Define "import statements aren't working", where's the code? Do you have the transitive dependencies necessary? What are the precise errors you get?

Comment: Wow. Hmm... Confusing. Why would they bother bundling it if they had no intention of bundling it? Completely useless, IMHO if I have to fiddle with dependencies to get it to work anyway.

Comment: So don't use it then, I guess. "Completely useless?" In what sense? It *is* bundled, and should be working out of the box if you're using any reasonable dependency mechanism as described in the link you've provided. YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gpars` is indeed shipped with groovy distribution - as you can see under `$GROOVY_HOME/lib` - but **it's still a separate library**.

If you use `groovysh` or `groovyConsole`, `gpars` is automatically added to classpath and ready to use.

However if you need to use `gpars` in a separate application managed by `gradle` or `maven` you need to define a [dependency](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.gpars%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gpars%22) to fetch and use `gpars`

Answer (score 2):

You can also add this to the top of your Groovy script or in the Groovy console, which has built in support for Grape's @Grab annotation:

> @Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.2.1')